# Change GRUB's variable using a C language

Tags: c, reboot, grub

I was wondering if there is any way for me to write a **C** program to change the value off GRUB's variables.

I need to write a program that can reboot my computer on another OS, for example:

- I am on Suse disk1

program changes GRUB's variable and reboot automatically.

- I am on Suse disk2

I would like to access variables like : title, root, kernel, initrd. But without editing the /boot/grub/menu.lst or grub.conf  file.

Is there an API for GRUB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why re-invent the wheel? Have a look at `grub-set-default`. This little tool set the default entry in the grub.cfg on the command line. This is just a little shellscript, but it should be enough for your needs.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed. But I cannot execute "grub-set-default" each time I have "command not found".

Comment: On SuSE, you may need to install the package `trustedgrub` first, as it contains the script.