# How to restart from windows and boot to winPE or DOS from usb - Using win boot manager

Tags: windows, usb, dos, portability, winpe

Just trying to figure out this little nugget of information. So far I have found a couple of examples that do a similar thing but doesn't quite explain how it is done. I am trying to create program that runs in windows and then reboots the computer and boots into a dos environment or winpe environment stored on a usb (where the program will be running from). Now I know its possible because things like acronis and avast do a similar thing where they reboot and run a pre boot environment to do stuff in and then run windows again.

Also the operating systems this primarily has to operate under is Win Vista, Win 7, Win 8, Win 8.1 and Win 10.

Some of the articles I have covered in my travels to try and find answers:

link: [dos boot before win7 boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891884/dos-boot-before-win7-boot)
now this was the closest to the answer I found which is to read the boot address for windows and then write an the address to boot to the winpe or dos location. But I'm unsure whether going down that path is the right path.

link: [Change GRUB's variable using a C language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6490006/change-grubs-variable-using-a-c-language)
This was disqualified as a possible route because it uses grub and using grub is not an option for this project (disappointing; I know)

link: [Restart a computer using function pointers in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26387105/restart-a-computer-using-function-pointers-in-c)
This I disqualified because it seemed to be sort of answering what I needed but wasn't sure whether it was the right direction again.

Kind of out of my depth here and any advice in the right direction would be awesome.

Also I'm new here so if there is any problems with my post please notify me and I will amend it to provide more information. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't do this with MS-DOS because it depends on BIOS support for reading and writing drives, and the BIOS only supports reading and writing from a USB drive if the BIOS boots from the USB drive. There's no general way of programically telling the BIOS to boot off a USB drive instead of the hard drive.

Comment: hmm, so would there be a way of getting windows to boot into an ms dos made as a partition of the hdd?

Comment: Sure, just mark the partition as active. The disk would have to use the MFT partition scheme though, as MS-DOS doesn't support GPT partitions and can't boot from UEFI.

Comment: Cool; now how would you get the MS-DOS partition to boot from a call in windows - As my plan is to get the original program to shrink the current main windows volume create a partition from the shrunk space - install MSDOS and the required programs that need to run under MSDOS then get it to reboot into that partition. Then later after everything I need done under MSDOS is done - reboot into windows and delete said MSDOS partition. I have figured out the volume shrink and the volume create ( I think(I have to do more testing - code currently a bit messy) )

Comment: You'd use IOCTL_DISK_SET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX to make the MS-DOS partition active and then use ExitWindowsEx reboot the computer.